# Moving div based on screen size

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, html

I have a site with 3 divs for layout purposes. The first is and outer container (1410px wide), the second is a left column (1110px wide) the last is a right column (300px wide).

Its a wordpress theme I want to modify. Initially it was on the left column (it was then the only container, for other purposes I've added the new outer container and right column)

When it was an original theme on an iPhone it would scale the site perfectly which was great. Since modifying its lost this ability.

In an ideal word I'd like to move the new right div to a position just under the nav bar when viewed on mobile devices and keep the scaling that was once in place.

The wordpress theme is called duet.

The only other way to achieve what I want would be to move the sidebar of the theme. If someone could tell me how to do that it would probably be better that what I'm trying to achieve

The site I'm trying it on is http://testbox1.martincwebd.com

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use media queries:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 2):

### These tutorials/blogs are amazingly helpful and easy to read, understand and implement.

**Essential reading on responsive design**

http://www.alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design

**Going even further with fluid design**

http://www.alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids

**Very good responsive design tutorial - straight to the point**

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

**Nifty responsive design tricks you can use**

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-useful-css-tricks-for-responsive-design